# integral of $e^\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus

Is there a way to evaluate $\int e^\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

I first used substitution, I let $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=u\implies \frac{-1}{2}x^\frac{-3}{2}dx=du$ and  also $x^\frac{-3}{2}=u^3$ so $dx=-2u^{-3}du$

After substituting, I now have to evaluate
$-2\int u^{-3}e^u du$ .

I then used integration by parts and ended up with 
$-2u^{-3}e^u+u^{-1}e^u-2e^u\ln u+2\int e^u\ln u du$

This is where I got the problem

Comment: Is this a part of finding a definite integral, or are you looking for an anti-derivative? I don't think there is an elementary anti-derivative, so it will probably involve [special functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5E(1%2Fsqrt(x))+dx).

Comment: Ok, thank you StackTD

Comment: $\displaystyle \int e^{x} \ln(x) dx = e^{x} \ln(x) - \int \frac{e^x}{x} dx$, and $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{e^t}{t}dt = \text{Ei}(x)$ a special function, see https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentielle_int%C3%A9grale